# what are the benifits of MVC pattern in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biggest advantage to using ASP.Net MVC vs web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms)

maybe it feels this question is repeating , but i just want to know this,what are the benefits of MVC pattern in asp.net ?

Comment: Sure is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623172/why-is-mvc-so-popular/3623185#3623185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links may help you:

- [ASP.NET MVC Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(VS.90).aspx)
- [HowTo: Basics of ASP.NET MVC or why MVC?](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/25/howto-basics-of-aspnet-mvc-or-why-mvc/)
- [Advantages of the ASP.NET MVC Approach](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Advantages-of-the-ASPNET-MVC-Approach/)

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102558/biggest-advantage-to-using-asp-net-mvc-vs-web-forms/114186#114186)