# Designing installation process

Tags: php

I want to create a CMS, installation and configuration is first. I want to do a couple of stages here:

1. Display page with server requirements
2. Display database configuration "window"
3. After clicking submit, display some other configuration window

etc. until it is finished.

---

My questions are strictly design issued:

1. How do I check if user already came through the installation process? I could create config.php file when it's done and check for its existence - is this a good solution? I think `file_exists()` would slow the application down a bit.
2. When I click "submit" in the stages at the top of this post, I'd need to redirect the request to the `config` class method - so the routing would be needed. Is this a good solution?
3. And finally, when I click the submit and I am in the class's method, doing something, I need to move user to the next window. How should I do this? Requiring html file from inside this method? Redirecting to the different method with the same file including?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with oop, would you mind editing the tags?

Comment: Well, the project is object-oriented...:P

Answer (score 0):

1. By creating a config file at the end of your installation process you're doing pretty well. Your application needs to pull the config data from a file anyways.
2. In a complex application such as a CMS you won't get around using some kind of routing, so yes it would be a pretty good solution.
3. Whether to redirect to another action or not depends on what you want to do. I'd keep each step as a seperate action in my controller. You defenitely should seperate your business logic from your output which means you need to load your html files inside in the actions of business logic.

Based on your questions I see that you might to read on some things yet. I suggest you to take a look on the MVC Pattern ([Why should I use MVC in a php website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936345/why-should-i-use-mvc-in-a-php-website)).

the second and the last of your questions will be clear to you automatically once you understood MVC.

*(to all potential downvoters: no, I'm not an "by hook or by crook" MVC preacher. But a CMS just is an application where MVC would come in handy )*

Comment: Config system lays in SYSTEM folder. I'd need MVC for this, and for example for admin system laying in the ADMIN folder. So I'd need to connect these parts with some base controller/model/view classes inside the CORE folder...isn't this a bit messy?

Comment: Well. I rather thought that you might want to use MVC for your whole application and not only for the installation process. It's utter normal that large applications share certain parts of the software.

Answer (score 0):

Ad1. You will probably have to make a connection to DB each time page is rendered, so you have to read config file anyway. You can add some redirect to installation page in case there is no config (you can also check some other things since it will be only checked when no config exception is raised).

Ad2. You don't need any fancy routing to do a redirect.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Ad3. I'm not sure what do you mean by "I am in the class's method". Do you use any PHP framework? You can only redirect between URL's which can be simply addresses of .php scripts on server or can be masked with `mod_rewrite` module (or similar in case you don't use Apache). So you should have at least one script for normal site viewing and other for installation. When installation is done, you redirect to regular script that handles requests.

As other suggest, I would also recommend you some further reading on **MVC pattern** and to take under consideration using some framework (Zend Framework as just one example).

Comment: I'd need routing to use <form action="www.example.com/system/config-class/set-db-connection">.

Comment: And I'm not sure how to build core classes using MVC pattern here. Is it really ok to use MVC only for config part of the system?

Comment: yes, you need routing whenever you want to use URL that do not represent actual address of the script you're calling.

Comment: I don't think using MVC only for configuration process is a good idea - it's a design pattern for managing whole application.